# DialogFragment TextView Width

Tags: android, android-fragments

I having trying to implement dialogFragments. They display and dismiss fine but the problem is the the width of the of dialog and also the textviews. The textviews will only ever be on one line when I would prefer then to span numerous. They also implement scrolling so the only way I can see all of the content is my scrolling with my finger.

here is the XML

```
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/website_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="@string/website_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/email_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/website_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="@string/email_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/information_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="@string/information_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/copyright_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/information_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="@string/copyright_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/apparentmedia_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/copyright_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="@string/apparentmedia_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Here is the DialogFragment

public class InformationDialog extends DialogFragment {

```
int mNum;

/**
 * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
 * as an argument.
 */
public static InformationDialog newInstance(int num) {
    InformationDialog d = new InformationDialog();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    d.setArguments(args);

    return d;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

    // Pick a style based on the num.
    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
        case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
    }
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 2: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Panel; break;
        case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme; break;
        case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Light; break;
        case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel; break;
        case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Light; break;
    }
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView websiteText, emailText;;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
    v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    websiteText =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.website_text);
    websiteText.setText(R.string.website_text);
    websiteText.setWidth(300);


    emailText =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email_text);
    emailText.setText(R.string.email_text);
    Linkify.addLinks(emailText, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);

    Linkify.addLinks(websiteText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    return v;
}
```

}

and how I call it

```
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialog.newInstance();

       newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Answer (score 1):

I never got an answer to this but I would assume lots of people had a problem with it as the android team [blogged about it](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)